# "Remote Desktop Client" updated, but NOT installed

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop, remote-control, malware, client

I just purchased a used iMac yesterday. Today, the app store updated "Apple Remote Desktop Client". I can not find an app called that in my app folder. Could it be hidden? Could this be used to 'spy' or grab info from my Mac?

[image: Update from App Store]

Comment: One point of confusion may be that Apple nowadays deploys system software updates via the App Store--it's not exclusively used for 3rd party apps. The software update in question has been deployed by Apple to all Macs, and it's in everyone's best interest to update to patch security holes. Also, if you purchased a used Mac and it had an existing user account, you really should have it wiped and reinstalled to be sure you are secure.

Answer (score 1):

Not patching that software is the most insecure thing - so approve the update. All OS X ship with some version of the Remote Desktop Client but it is not enabled by default.

Secure your Mac if you don't want this by:

1. **Turn on the firewall** in the security preference pane
2. Open sharing preference pane and deselect **Screen Sharing** and **Remote Management** if they are checked.
3. Don't let people know your user name, short user name or password or re-use a password with another service that could get compromised and then be used to try that same password against your Mac.

It's not malware, but malware could be used to change the settings or snoop your password (key logger) or phish you to enter your username and password where it can then use it for bad purposes. Out of the box, you shouldn't be open to exploits due to Apple shipping the Remote Desktop Client on OS X.